# How to combine bumps and dimples?

Tags: graphics

I'm working on a set of diagrams to try to make interesting math activities for positive and negative integers.  These diagrams look like this.

[image: 3D illusion, 4 bumps and 3 dimples.]

(This diagram would represent 4-3=1.  Later, I'll test this out to see if students actually see it this way.)

What I'd like to do is to create animations where the bumps and dimples combine and become a 'flat' surface.

My first attempt is just to have gray in the overlap zone, which isn't too bad.
[image]

What I'd like is to have the overlap zone more gradually transition from the bump through to the dimple.

---

Here's the basic Mathematica code I used to create these images.

```
Unit[θ_] := {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}

Dimple[r_, ϕ_] := Translate[Polygon[Table[Unit[θ], {θ, 0, 360*Degree, 
(360*Degree)/80}], VertexColors -> Table[Blend[{White, Black}, (1 + Sin[θ])/2], {θ, 0, 
360*Degree, (360*Degree)/80}]], r*Unit[ϕ]]

Bump[r_, ϕ_] := Translate[Polygon[Table[Unit[θ], {θ, 0, 360*Degree, 
(360*Degree)/80}], VertexColors -> Table[Blend[{Black, White}, (1 + Sin[θ])/2], {θ, 0, 
360*Degree, (360*Degree)/80}]], r*Unit[ϕ]]

OverLapTable[d_] := Join[Table[Unit[θ] - {d, 0}, {θ, -ArcCos[d], ArcCos[d], 0.01}],  
Table[Unit[θ] + {d, 0}, {θ, 180*Degree - ArcCos[d], 180*Degree + ArcCos[d], 0.01}]]

Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Bump[0.5, 0], Dimple[0.5, 180*Degree], Gray, 
Polygon[OverLapTable[0.5]]}]
```

---

**Additional**

This sort of a side view of what I'm hoping to accomplish,
[image]

with a smooth transition between the dimple and the bump.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code, wuyud!  I didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One can try `Opacity`:

```
Graphics[{{Gray, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}, {Opacity[0.9], 
   Bump[0.5, 0]}, {Opacity[0.9], Dimple[0.5, 180*Degree]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's not bad, but I was hoping for something that would transition a little better.